# RxTest: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 and arm64

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa, rxtest

I am trying to run the following test from **Chapter 16: Testing with RxTest** of **[Raywenderlich RxSwift](https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/rxswift)** book:

```
import XCTest
import RxSwift
import RxTest
@testable import Testing

class TestingViewModel : XCTestCase {

var viewModel: ViewModel!
var scheduler: ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler!

override func setUp() {
super.setUp()

viewModel = ViewModel()
scheduler = ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .default)
}

func testColorNameIsRayWenderlichGreenWhenHexStringIs006636() {

// 1
let colorNameObservable = viewModel.colorName.asObservable().subscribeOn(scheduler)

// 2
viewModel.hexString.value = "#006636"

// 3
XCTAssertEqual("rayWenderlichGreen", try! colorNameObservable.toBlocking().first()!)
 }
}
```

But I get this error on the simulator:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "type metadata for RxCocoa.DriverSharingStrategy", referenced from:
>         TestingTests.TestingViewModel.testColorNameIsRayWenderlichGreenWhenHexStringIs006636() -> () in TestingViewModel.o
>     "protocol witness table for RxCocoa.DriverSharingStrategy : RxCocoa.SharingStrategyProtocol in RxCocoa", referenced from:
>         TestingTests.TestingViewModel.testColorNameIsRayWenderlichGreenWhenHexStringIs006636() -> () in TestingViewModel.o
>     "RxCocoa.SharedSequence.asObservable() -> RxSwift.Observable", referenced from:
>         TestingTests.TestingViewModel.testColorNameIsRayWenderlichGreenWhenHexStringIs006636() -> () in TestingViewModel.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And This one on iPhone 6s:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "type metadata for RxCocoa.DriverSharingStrategy", referenced from:
>         TestingTests.TestingViewModel.testColorNameIsRayWenderlichGreenWhenHexStringIs006636() -> () in TestingViewModel.o
>     "protocol witness table for RxCocoa.DriverSharingStrategy : RxCocoa.SharingStrategyProtocol in RxCocoa", referenced from:
>         TestingTests.TestingViewModel.testColorNameIsRayWenderlichGreenWhenHexStringIs006636() -> () in TestingViewModel.o
>     "RxCocoa.SharedSequence.asObservable() -> RxSwift.Observable", referenced from:
>         TestingTests.TestingViewModel.testColorNameIsRayWenderlichGreenWhenHexStringIs006636() -> () in TestingViewModel.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Unfortunately, there is no support for this issue in Raywenderlich's forums.](https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/chapter-16-testing-with-rxtest/34926)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of searches, As somebody suggests [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1583) for another similar issue I found that this error will be solved by importing `RxCocoa`.